# Exit Pop Up and Internal Links

Tags: javascript

I have this exit pop up script when a user exits a page

```
var triedToLeave = false;
function onBeforeUnload(){
    triedToLeave = true;
    return "you can put your own message here";
}
setInterval( function (){
     if( triedToLeave ){
         window.removeEventListener( "beforeunload", onBeforeUnload, false );
         document.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
     }
}, 2000 );
window.addEventListener( "beforeunload", onBeforeUnload, false);
```

However, if you click on a link within the site, it triggers the pop up.  Can somebody please tell me what I need to add to prevent internal links from triggering the exit pop up?  Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You need to add a click handler to all the links that removes the `beforeunload` listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a click handler to all links that disables the `beforeunload` handler.

```
function removeBeforeUnload() {
    window.removeEventListener( "beforeunload", onBeforeUnload, false );
}

window.onload = function() {
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
        allLinks[i].addEventListener("click", removeBeforeUnload, false);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do I add that code to the end of my current javascript code?

Comment: You can put it anywhere after the document is loaded.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I added the code right after my pop up code and it isnt working.  Sorry, I am not that savy with javascript.

Comment: I've moved it into the `window.onload` handler. See if that helps.

Comment: Barmar you are a life saver!  Thank you so much for your help! The users on Stack Overflow are always so helpful and so kind.  Thanks!